# Add a fragment id to a Zend redirect

Tags: zend-framework2

Maybe I'm goofy and can't find the documentation. I want to add a fragment id to the end of the URL used in a controller action redirection. This is kind of what I want to do:

```
return $this->redirect()->toRoute('jobapplication',array('action'=>'edit','id'=>$candidateclass->application_id,'fragment'=>'candidateclass'));
```

All I get is this:

```
http://localhost/Zend/public/jobapplication/edit/21
```

And I want this:

```
http://localhost/Zend/public/jobapplication/edit/21#candidateclass
```

Thoughts?

Comment: use string concatenation? :-) dirty, but nice.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You pass the fragment in the `$options` array, which is the third parameter of the `toRoute()` method, try...

```
return $this->redirect()->toRoute(
    'jobapplication', 
    array('action' => 'edit', 'id' => $candidateclass->application_id), 
    array('fragment' => 'candidateclass')
);
```

Comment: Awesome! Tried it and it works. I've been beating my head against the wall trying to find documentation on it. Thanks!